# Difference between config and application

Tags: jsp, servlets, scriptlet

While learning about jsp come to know about config and application object and then see the similarity between both of them.

seems both have same functionality

Is there any difference.

Here is the code

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>  
<servlet>  
<servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>  
<jsp-file>/welcome.jsp</jsp-file>  

<init-param>  
<param-name>dname</param-name>  
<param-value>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</param-value>  
</init-param>  

</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>       
</web-app>
```

using config

```
<%   
out.print("Welcome "+request.getParameter("uname"));  

String driver=config.getInitParameter("dname");  
out.print("driver name is="+driver);  
%>
```

using application

```
<%   
out.print("Welcome "+request.getParameter("uname"));  

String driver=application.getInitParameter("dname");  
out.print("driver name is="+driver);  

%>
```

Comment: this may help you out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm

Comment: if you got the answer for this please close it.

Comment: Confirm the best answers below and close this @sparsh610

Answer (score 0):

Config is for a specific Servlet/JSP, the config parameter are unknown to other Servlet/JSP  and it has Session Scope.

application( ServletContext ) parameter are specified for the entire application. These variables are access across the application.

Comment: it depends, if you want to pass some parameter to a specific Servlet/jsp during init() call then use config. If you want to share a global value to all Servlet/JSP then use application ( ServletContext).

Answer (score 0):

**config** is an implicit object of type **ServletConfig**

**application** is an implicit object of type **ServletContext**

**config** can be used to get initialization parameter for a **particular** JSP page

**application** initialization parameter can be used by **all** jsp pages

**Application** is created only once by the web container when application or project is deployed on the server

**config** is created by the web container for each jsp page

here you can see more examples :

Jsp config >> https://www.javatpoint.com/config-implicit-object

Jsp Application >>https://www.javatpoint.com/application-implicit-object

Comment: Could you post an important part your examples here with link to these examples?